# AWS RDS Track incoming connections and where they were initiated

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I understand that there are means of auditing database connections in posgresql. I have studied the below articles:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-postgresql-query-logging/

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/track-failed-login-rds-postgresql/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.LoggingAndMonitoring.html

However none of these seem to indicate that there is an "out of the box" way to, for example, see if a connection came in at 4am last Tuesday to your database and then disconnected.

Audit is there, but some statement has to be made to be tracked, and logging failed connections seems possible but again, that doesn't help in this instance.

So, specifically with AWS RDS Postgresql, does anyone know if there is a historic view of connections available anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: I see the acticles you linked have all the piece of information you need. 
What specifically you are looking for?

Comment: I am looking for a historic view of connection data and to know if that is there, out of the box. I.P. address, source of connection, whether or not it came into the database.

Comment: The log should contain the information you needed. It is in the textual format only so no easy format and filtering on dashboards/tables out of the box but you can query for the information you need with the Cloudwatch query language